# Adding input box values to existing object based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of data that is rendered via an api call. It displays 4 values from the initial object. I mainly care about the `name` value as this is what's important later in a post request.

Each row in the table has a checkbox. When the checkbox is selected (`true`) the name associated with that checkbox is added to an object called `selectedFields`, as an object. For example If I select the checkbox with name `id` it creates an object store like:

```
  "selectedFields": {
    "id" : {}
  }
```

This works fine and well. However, I've added 3 input boxes that are associated with each `name`. The inputs are `lengthType`, `size`, `maxArrayElements`, which are of course user selectable.
What I'm having trouble with is adding these values back to the object so it looks like:

```
  "selectedFields": {
    "id": {
       lengthType: Variable,
       size: 1,
       maxArrayElements: 1
    },
    "price": {
       lengthType: Fixed,
       size: 10,
       maxArrayElements: 1
    }
  }
```

How can I add these 3 values back to the `name` object that was created so it looks like the above example?

I don't want to post a wall of code, so I'm posting the checkbox function that handles creating the `selectedFields` object with the appropriate selected `names`. I suspect that the input values should get added here somehow, but I'm not sure.

```
 checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => {
//handle check box of each fieldName
const obj = this.state.fieldNames.find(field => field.name === name);
if (isChecked === true) {
  //checked conditional
  this.setState(
    {
      selectedFields: {
        ...this.state.selectedFields,
        [name]: {
          ...obj
        }
      }
    },
    () => {
      console.log(
        "callback in  isChecked if conditional",
        this.state.selectedFields
      );
    }
  );
} else {
  const newSelectedFields = this.state.selectedFields;
  delete newSelectedFields[name];
  this.setState(
    {
      selectedFields: newSelectedFields
    },
    () => {
      console.log(
        `box unchecked, deleted from object --->`,
        this.state.selectedFields
      );
    }
  );
}
```

};

You will have to make the first dropdown selection to view the data.

[CodeSandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/createqueryschema-table-rewrite-6drgg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

You need to change a few things because nothing is stating where to assign the new state outside of the root state object.

---

**Handlers in your Index.js**:

Your handlers for the change events aren't looking for the name of the object to determine if it exists or not. If you want to add it to the specified child object you better be sure it's there.

We adjust the handlers to take an object name and setState with `object.assign` on that specific object if it exists:

*note*: since `lengthType` doesn't have a `name` property we simply provide it with a string. `e.currentTarget` will provide the option span, not the root `Dropdown` element, so even supplying a `name` property to that component wouldn't allow us to use `e.currentTarget.name` - you may want to consult the [Semantic UI documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) if you would prefer something different. I gave it a quick scan but didn't want to deep dive it.

```
  handleChange = (e, obj_name) => {
    if (this.state.selectedFields[obj_name]) {
      let selectedFields = Object.assign({}, this.state.selectedFields);
      selectedFields[obj_name] = Object.assign(
        this.state.selectedFields[obj_name],
        { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
      );
      this.setState({ selectedFields });
    }
  };

  onLengthTypeChange = (e, obj_name) => {
    if (this.state.selectedFields[obj_name]) {
      let selectedFields = Object.assign({}, this.state.selectedFields);
      selectedFields[obj_name] = Object.assign(
        this.state.selectedFields[obj_name],
        { lengthType: e.currentTarget.textContent }
      );
      this.setState({ selectedFields });
    }
  };
```

The above, of course, won't work if you don't adjust your `onChange` events on your components so that, in addition to your event object, they also send your object name.

---

**Handlers in your Component file**:

*Note*: It was odd because in your `Index.js` file you seemed to half do this with `lengthType` but you weren't passing over additional data. You can't simply pass parameters into a handler - to get it to work you need to pass an anonymous function to the `onChange` properties that will take the event and pass it on to the handler functions **with** your object name:

```
      <Table.Cell>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Pick a length Type:"
          clearable
          selection
          search
          fluid
          noResultsMessage="Please search again"
          label="lengthType"
          multiple={false}
          options={lengthTypeOptions}
          header="Choose a Length Type"
          onChange={e => onLengthTypeChange(e, name)}
          value={lengthType}
          required
        />
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
        <Input
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.size}
          type="number"
          name="size"
          min="1"
          placeholder="1"
          required
        />
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
        <Input
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.maxArrayElements}
          type="number"
          name="maxArrayElements"
          placeholder="1"
          min="1"
          max="100"
          required
        />
      </Table.Cell>
```

Once these things are adjusted, the code will update the specified properties on the child objects after the corresponding checkbox is **selected**.

---

### Final Note:

I did not adjust it to save the previous state if you **uncheck** and then **check** the box. It wasn't specified in your question and I don't want to make assumptions.

---

### Code Sandbox:

The adjusted code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/createqueryschema-table-rewrite-bwvo4?fontsize=14

---

### Additional Recommendations:

- In your initial state your `selectedFields` is declared as an `Array` and then it is promptly turned into an `Object` when any checkbox is selected. I would suggest not doing this. **Changing data types on a property during the course of running an application is very much asking for trouble.**
- When a checkbox is loaded  you provide a `checkbox` function from your `Index.js` file. This is simply called `box` in your component. I would suggest keeping the names of properties and state equivalent when passing down from parent to child. It is much, much, much easier for someone else to come in and maintain if they have to - not to mention easier to retain your own sanity.
- The above `checkbox` function takes props from child and passes them up to the parent. This would be the place to pass your collected data into a cache on the parent, into local/session storage, or whatever you want to do with your data. You could instead write code to the effect of: if the checkbox is selected when an input handler is called *do* a save - but I would say that it would probably be best on `render` since the screen is constantly updating anyway and you have the `checkbox` function readily passing props currently. **This is preference, so it's your call**

---

Good luck! Hope this helped!

Comment: You touched on every single part that I was struggling with / questioning. Thank you. On your first recommendation, I actually just found out that `selectedFields` needs to be an array of objects (selected checkboxes). `"selectedFields": [ { "name": "nameOne", "lengthType": "fixed" .. etc } , { "name": "nameTwo" .. etc } ]`

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble getting `selectedFields` to be the desired data type/structure as I mentioned above. Do the change handlers also need to be reworked?

Comment: @DJ2 they shouldn't need to be. Adjusting for the data structure is really mostly handled within the Index file. What you would have to do though, since instead of finding a property of the `selectedFields` object you're looking for an object within an array to update, it would likely be easiest to: a) `filter` for the object, adjust it, and replace it in the original array or b) `reduce` the original array and replace it with the returned array.

Comment: Mind sharing a basic example if possible?

Comment: @DJ2 I can, but I may not be able to tonight. I'm working on quite a few different things. This may be worth creating another question in the meantime.

Comment: So I did post a new question else where and got the desired structure but I think the change handlers need to be updated since they're no longer being added to the `name` object that is checked. https://codesandbox.io/s/o7jnvlnj0y

Comment: @DJ2 Apologies this kind of slipped my mind. I'll take a look at some point today.

Comment: no worries, The `name` itself is no longer an object, so it needs to be added into the same object that contains the `name`

Comment: I changed around the `onLengthTypeChange` method, but still can't seem to get the inputs to add back to the checked `[obj_name]`

Comment: How would you go about saving the previous of the object if the box is unchecked/checked?